# How does warpPerspective in OpenCV works

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I have recently started exploring OpenCV and I am having trouble to understand warpPerspective, documentation does not help much. I mean why is it used? And if I need to resize an image, I can use resize method, then what additional benefit will i get using warpPerspective method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple, `warpPerspective` allows you to create a new image from a transformation matrix.

It is much more powerful than a resizing function.

**Simple summary :**

[image]

**Example with a very popular application**

You have picture 2 above and want to extract the document (result in picture 3).

Get the template of it (picture 1) and compute the homography (transformation matrix between picture 1 and picture 2).

Using this transformation, you will be able to create image number 3 using the transformation matrix in `warpPerspective`.

[image]

Example from [an article from learnOpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/) written by Satya Mallick

Comment: Thanks @emlot77 for the explanation.

Comment: This answers what `warpPerspective` does, not how it works.